# How many custom roles can we create for an enterprise Azure app?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I would like to understand if I can use Azure AD authentication for our enterprise application. Basically we have a service that manages component data for several thousand product teams in my company. The requirement is team A can only view their data. According to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=59YwW8FrLm8, we can create custom roles in an Azure app and assign them to different client apps. My concern is that is there a limit on how many roles we can create in the app? We have several thousand product teams to support. Also, is there any performance impact on large number of custom roles in an app?

The bigger question is if we should utilize Azure OIDC to do this authorization. Is this something that we are better off writing our own authorization logic?

Comment: As mentioned in [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles#custom-role-limits), Upto 5000 custom roles are allowed for each tenant.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed that by default, it is 5000.